# Sort 2D array rows

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2D array which I need to sort it's rows only, and I have done with this code:

```
double[][] arr = initArray();

    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        int index = row;
        double minVal = arr[row][0];
        for (int column = 0; column < arr[row].length; column++) {

            if (arr[row][column] < minVal) {
                minVal = arr[row][column];
                index = column;
            }

        }


        arr[row][index] = arr[row][0];
        arr[row][0] = minVal;

    }
```

Sample input:

```
{{0.15, 0.875, 0.375},
 {0.55, 0.005, 0.225},
 {0.30, 0.12, 0.4}}
```

Expect out put:

```
0.15 0.375 0.875 
0.005 0.225 0.55 
0.12 0.3 0.4
```

What I get:

```
0.15 0.875 0.375 
0.005 0.55 0.225 
0.12 0.3 0.4
```

Comment: 2d array is array of arrays `{ {...}, {...}, {...} }`. Your current code doesn't sort internal arrays, it is searching for minimum in each row and moves it at start of that row. Try to think of way to sort 1d array and then apply it to each row.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @jontro thanks for pointing that, but it's not duplication here, I said `rows`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pshemo mentioned, you didn't go through all your values, here is a prob way:

```
 for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < arr.length - 1; column++) {
            double min = arr[row][column];
            int index = column;
            for (int j = column + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (min > arr[row][j]) {
                    min = arr[row][j];
                    index = j;
                }
            }
            if (index != column) {
                arr[row][index] = arr[row][column];
                arr[row][column] = min;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Arrays.sort(); function from the java.util.Arrays class to sort each row in your 2d Array.

```
 for (double[] innerArray: outerArray) {
     Arrays.sort(innerArray);
 }
```

EDIT: Here is the entire example:

```
double[][] outerArray = {
     {
         0.15,
         0.875,
         0.375
     },
     {
         0.55,
         0.005,
         0.225
     },
     {
         0.30,
         0.12,
         0.4
     }
 };


 for (double[] innerArray: outerArray) {
     Arrays.sort(innerArray);
 }


 for (int i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++) {

     for (int j = 0; j < outerArray.length; j++) {

         System.out.print(outerArray[i][j] + " ");

     }
     System.out.println();

 }
```

Comment: This won't work unfortunately, I need row only.

Comment: Okay. I posted the entire code check it out and you will see the results yourself.

Comment: Yes I have upvoted to you thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int column = 0; column < arr[row].length; column++) {
        //**insert another for loop here**
            if (arr[row][column] < minVal) {
              minVal = arr[row][column];
              index = column;
            }

        }
```

Your code is running once per row, and hence it is only finding the smallest and shifting to first position. You just have to make sure that the same action happens as many times as there ar items in the row. Look here for reference [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)